# I would like to send users an email if they have flashcard decks with cards open for review

Tags: php, arrays, email, multidimensional-array

I have an array with information about the user (username, email address) and flashcards (card id, deck name, deck description, topic, tags).

What I would like to achieve is that I get the number of open cards per flashcard deck per user so I can send one email to the users with all the flashcard decks where there are card to be reviewed (eg. user x has flashcard deck y with 17 to be reviewed cards and deck z with 5 cards to be reviewed).

This is the multidimensional array that I have (names and emails are fictive):

```
[0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (7) { 
["card_id"]=> string(5) "15468" 
["deck_name"]=> string(21) "Count to 10 in French" 
["description"]=> string(48) "Count to 10 in French language. English   - French" 
["topic_name"]=> string(9) "Languages" 
["deck_tags"]=> string(0) "" 
["userName"]=> string(11) "Scott Meier"         
["userEmail"]=> string(20) "xy@gmail.com" } 

[1]=> object(stdClass)#9 (7) { 
["card_id"]=> string(5) "15469" 
["deck_name"]=> string(21) "Count to 10 in French" 
["description"]=> string(48) "Count to 10 in French language. English - French" 
["topic_name"]=> string(9) "Languages" 
["deck_tags"]=> string(0) "" 
["userName"]=> string(11) "Scott Meier" 
["userEmail"]=> string(20) "xy@gmail.com" } 

[2]=> object(stdClass)#10 (7) { 
["card_id"]=> string(5) "15475" 
["deck_name"]=> string(21) "Count to 10 in French" 
["description"]=> string(48) "Count to 10 in French language. English - French" 
["topic_name"]=> string(9) "Languages" 
["deck_tags"]=> string(0) "" 
["userName"]=> string(11) "Fritz Weber" 
["userEmail"]=> string(20) "fritzweber@gmail.com" } 

[3]=> object(stdClass)#11 (7) { 
["card_id"]=> string(5) "15522" 
["deck_name"]=> string(28) "1030 words Spanish - English" 
["description"]=> string(64) "1030 Spanish most essential words in  Spanish (Spanish - English)" 
["topic_name"]=> string(9) "Languages" 
["deck_tags"]=> string(0) "" 
["userName"]=> string(11) "Christian Moser" 
["userEmail"]=> string(20) "cm@gmail.com" }
```

What I tried is a loop like this:

```
for ($i = $users = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
    echo $emails[$i]->userName; 
    echo $emails[$i]->userEmail; 
    echo $emails[$i]->deck_name;
}
```

The problem is that it will give me each user multiple times for each open card and when I send an email in the loop the users will get an email for each open card. What I want to achieve is that I can group all the flashcard decks with open cards per user so I can just send out 1 email per user including the information about the decks and how many cards need to be tested. How would I do that?

Comment: So you are going to have to code something to do that, and it does not look like you have even tried. SO is **not a free coding  service**

Comment: @RiggsFolly As you can see in my previous two questions I always try to solve the problems that arise. As I am new to programming what you see in the question (loop) is all that I could come up with. I am not asking for a full fletched answer / code. Even a keyword or two that point me in the right direction would be sufficient so I can give it a shot and update the question. Thank you for your consideration.